# What is wrong with my syntax for mysqldbcopy?

Tags: mysql

Just trying to do a simple mysqldbcopy using meekrodb's "query" function:

```
DB::query("mysqldbcopy $seeddb:$dbName --source=$user:$password@$seedhost --destination=$user:$password@$host");
```

The resulting string has all of my information in it:

```
mysqldbcopy seed_v1:core --source=root:password@localhost --destination=root:password@localhost
```

But I get the dreaded "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax"

I noticed in the documentation, they were using "\" but I was assuming they were using this because it was going on a separate line...  I've tried it with and without them...

Comment: Server version: 5.6.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL) / mysql-utilities 1.5.4

Answer (score 4):

mysqldbcopy is a SYSTEM COMMAND not a command that should be ran within MySQL...

Once I removed it from the query and ran:

```
exec("mysqldbcopy seed_v1:core --source=root:password@localhost --destination=root:password@localhost");
```

It ran fine.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it's a system command. I was running it insite MySQL shell. Shame. :P